# Is there any publicly available Radiology dataset for NLP (Natural Language Processing) purposes?

Tags: data-request, medical, nlp

I'm looking for publicly available Radiology reports data collection which I can use to proceed with my research. Do you happen to know some?

Comment: Kind of confused since radiology makes people think image processing and you asked for NLP

Comment: Please read [What a good request looks like](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)